# Java Spark sql Dataset<Row> write parquet

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

While writing Dataset< Row > to Parquet got following error.

```
data.write().option("compression",snappy").format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(filePath);
```

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOptions$    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOptions.(ParquetOptions.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOptions.(ParquetOptions.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.prepareWrite(ParquetFileFormat.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
>     at
>   package.common.dao.service.spark.utils.SparkDataBaseUtilImpl.writeParquetFile(SparkDataBaseUtilImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   package.common.dao.service.spark.SparkImportServiceImpl.csvFileImport(SparkImportServiceImpl.java:29)
>     at
>   package.common.dao.service.spark.SparkDaoServiceImpl.dataImport(SparkDaoServiceImpl.java:70)
>     at
>   package.common.dao.service.spark.SparkDaoServiceImpl.executeOperations(SparkDaoServiceImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   package.controller.ServiceDao.fetchJobDetailsByJobId(ServiceDao.java:28)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I checked all dependency every thing seems to be fine.I am using the lastest spark version 2.4.0.

Comment: Is your app running behind a web server as I see: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742). Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: Yes I am running it on Tomcat Server as  Java (JAX-RS) project using Jersey.

Comment: Try out of Tomcat... Sounds like a class path issue.

Comment: All required jars are on the classpath. I am able to write CSV format but when I try to write parquet it gives above error.